# Remove column based on header name type

Tags: python, pandas

usually when you want to remove columns which are not of type `float`, you can write `pd.DataFrame.select_dtypes(include='float64')`. however i would like to remove a column in cases where the **header name** is not a float

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a' : [1,2,3], 10 : [3,4,5]})
df.dtypes
```

will give the output

```
a   int64
10   int64
dtype: object
```

how can i remove the column `a` based on the fact that it's not a `float` or `int`?

Comment: What about a column named `'28'` (as string)? Do you want to keep it, or remove it?

Comment: Hmm, good question. I want to remove it. Maybe by making sure that all header names that are applicable to be of type `float`, should be just that. And the rest should be removed. So for example: `28` should be kept, but `Unnamed: 28` should be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please Try drop column with digit using regex if you wanted to drop `10`

```
df.filter(regex='\d', axis=1)

#On the contrary, you can drop nondigits too

   # df.filter(regex='\D', axis=1)
```

Comment: wow, this worked seemlessly for a column named `a`! However if I changed the name to a more complicated string like `Unnamed: 28`, it doesn't work. can i change the regex input to make it work for all `string`-types?

Comment: Yap, try exlude any alphabets by `df.filter(regex='^[^a-z]+$', axis=1)` or exclude digits `df.filter(regex='[^\d+]', axis=1)`. This should achieve contrary outcomes as well

Comment: big thanks, i'm actually using the solution `df.filter(regex='^[^a-z]+$', axis=1)` now so i'll give you the green tick. i'll have to read up a bit on how to use regex aswell, this seems powerful

Comment: I upvoted this answer! It's very good! Just to note that `^[^a-z]+$` will keep columns with characters like `$^~\`/`, uppercase letters, and etc (only if there's no [a-z]).

Answer (score 1):

A solution based on type enumeration:

### Code

```
sr_dtype = df.dtypes
df = df.drop(columns=sr_dtype.index[
    sr_dtype.index.map(lambda el: not isinstance(el, (int, float)))  # add more if necessary
])
```

Note that `df.types` itself is a `Series` instance that regular `Series` operations are applicable. In particular, `index.map()` is used as a wrapper for `isinstance()` check in this example.

### Result

```
print(df)
   10
0   3
1   4
2   5
```

Comment: i changed `isinstance(el, (int, float))` to `isinstance(el, (str))` and it worked, thank you!

Comment: To delete non-int, float, etc., use this function: `lambda el: not isinstance(el, ...)`. The answer is revised.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that's the right output? Your dataframe columns are 'a' and 10, why your input has a column named 'b'?

Anyway, to remove the column `a`, regardless to its type but through its header name, use the `drop` method:
`df = df.drop(columns=['a'])`
Also works with a list of columns as well, instead of the single element list in this case.

Comment: sorry had written wrong, it was supposed to say 10, not b!

Answer (score 0):

Based in the other answers, you can also try:

1) To make sure to keep only `float` and `int` types:

```
df[[col for col in df.columns if type(col) in [float,int]]]
```

2) To just exclude string-like columns:

```
df.loc[:, [not isinstance(col, str) for col in df.columns]] # return bool array
# or
df[[col for col in df.columns if not isinstance(col, str)]] # return colum names
```

3) To exclude columns that's not `float`/`int` based on regex:

```
df.filter(regex='^\d+$|^\d+?\.{1}\d+$')
```

where the first expression `^\d+$` map integers (start and end with digit), and the second expression `^\d+?\.{1}\d+$` maps floats. We could just use `^[\d|\.]+$` (allowing only digits and points) to map both of them, but it would also maps columns like "1..2".